# web service with office 365

Tags: office-365, web-services, sms

we have a requirement to be able to send sms message via sharepoint online (office 365 ) and we are subscribe with provider this service : https://www.mobily.ws/en/
and they give us web service link with office 365 : http://www.mobilywebservices.com/SMSWebService/SMSIntegration.asmx

i  created html page in sharepoint designer for sending sms , what i need is the code for send button .
i am beginer with sharepoint , and i don't know how to use web service
Hope to help us
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This requires some medium-advanced knowledge and understanding of JavaScript.

In summary, you need to do the following (this is of course 1 of 1k different approaches):

- Add a HTML button, give a unique ID which you will reference later. Let's call this "sendSMSButton"
- Add JavaScript (add a JS file to your assets library, then link it on the page from a content editor web part) file, which you will use to make the call.
- Add a framework (e.g. jquery) to simplify Ajax requests and event handling.
- Add an event to the button, using the following  (assuming JQuery):

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#sendSMSButton").click(function () {
    // Put your custom API javascript here. This is called when the button is clicked.
  });
});

- The web service site appears to provide some JavaScript API samples you can use to get going.

Alternatively, you could create a [SharePoint workflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558.aspx) using SharePoint designer, and call the web service inside the workflow. This could be triggered by a list item added, such as a "Notify User" list.

Comment: Clarification: This answer is to get you started and more importantly heading in the right direction. It is not intended to be a comprehensive solution.

Comment: Thanks Russell , I prefer to create sharepoint workflow , and run when user add an item , i can use call http action and i used it with json for retrieving items of list and save the result in dictionary ,,, but how can i use call http with this service .

Comment: You need to find a REST web service endpoint from your provider (they will probably have one), then use the "Call HTTP Web Service" action in your workflow. There is detailed documentation for this over at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567558.aspx